# How do I parse and write XML using Python's ElementTree without moving namespaces around?

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, nunit, elementtree

Our project gets from upstream XML of this form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="foo" value="default">
    ...
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

It then reads/parses this XML using ElementTree, and then for every app setting matching a certain key ("foo"), it writes a new value that *it* knows about that the upstream process doesn't ( in this case key "foo" should have the value "bar").

The *downstream* process consuming the filtered XML is, aaahhhh... *fragile*. It expects to receive the XML in *exactly* the form above.

If I parse this XML without registering a namespace, then ElementTree mangles my tree like this on input:

```
<configuration xmlns:ns0="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <runtime>
  <ns0:assemblyBinding>
    <ns0:dependentAssembly>
      <ns0:assemblyIdentity culture="neutral" name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
      <ns0:bindingRedirect newVersion="7.0.0.0" oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" />
    </ns0:dependentAssembly>
  </ns0:assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
 <appSettings>
    <add key="foo" value="default">
    ...
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The downstream process can't handle this, because it's no clever enough to realize that, semantically, this is the same thing. So, I decide to register the namespace I know the upstream process will provide as a default namespace to avoid the prefixes showing up everywhere, and now I get this:

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
 <runtime>
  <assemblyBinding>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity culture="neutral" name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
      <bindingRedirect newVersion="7.0.0.0" oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
 <appSettings>
    <add key="foo" value="default">
    ...
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I don't know much about XML, but this also the downstream component cries about, and it seems to me that doesn't now mean this default `xmlns` now apply to *all* included elements inside `<configuration>`, whereas before it *only* applied to the `<assemblyBinding>` element?

Is there anyway, *using ElementTree*, to handle this namespace so that I can take in the upstream's XML, set `foo`'s value, and then pass that on downstream, without moving the namespace around, and leaving it exactly as I found it?

- I could use an lxml-based solution, which seems to handle this, *however*, lxml has a dependency on C which the downstream component would really like not to have to support: a pure Python solution is preferable.
- I could read the document as HTML which would ignore the namespace attribute, let me manipulate the value I want, and then pass on the document; *however*, I have yet to find a Python parser that doesn't downcase all the element names, and my downstream component requires the casing on all element names to be preserved.
- I could resort to string parsing and regular expressions. I would rather not write my own parser.

The only advice I could find so far about namespace handling in ElementTree suggests the "register a default namespace to avoid prefixes" approach, which I assumed would be suitable, but ElementTree then insists on moving the `xmlns` declaration up to the root node upon dumping.

I could also be clever build up a string that dumps the tree out in stages and in exactly the right order to put the `xmlns` declaration back on the "right node", but that strikes me, also, as pretty darned fragile.

Has anyone managed to get past a problem like this?

Comment: I have the same exact issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663191/keep-existing-namespaces-when-overwriting-xml-file-with-elementtree-and-python

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the solution that better suits your needs is to write a pure Python custom rendering using the features exposed by `xml.etree.ElementTree`. Here is one possible solution:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from re import findall, sub

def render(root, buffer='', namespaces=None, level=0, indent_size=2, encoding='utf-8'):
    buffer += f'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="{encoding}" ?>\n' if not level else ''
    root = root.getroot() if isinstance(root, ET.ElementTree) else root
    _, namespaces = ET._namespaces(root) if not level else (None, namespaces)
    for element in root.iter():
        indent = ' ' * indent_size * level
        tag = sub(r'({[^}]+}\s*)*', '', element.tag)
        buffer += f'{indent}<{tag}'
        for ns in findall(r'{[^}]+}', element.tag):
            ns_key = ns[1:-1]
            if ns_key not in namespaces: continue
            buffer += ' xmlns' + (f':{namespaces[ns_key]}' if namespaces[ns_key] != '' else '') + f'="{ns_key}"'
            del namespaces[ns_key]
        for k, v in element.attrib.items():
            buffer += f' {k}="{v}"'
        buffer += '>' + element.text.strip() if element.text else '>'
        children = list(element)
        for child in children:
            sep = '\n' if buffer[-1] != '\n' else ''
            buffer += sep + render(child, level=level+1, indent_size=indent_size, namespaces=namespaces)
        buffer += f'{indent}</{tag}>\n' if 0 != len(children) else f'</{tag}>\n'
    return buffer
```

By issuing the`XML` data you gave, to the above `render` function as show below:

```py
data=\
'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="foo" value="default" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>'''

e = ET.fromstring(data)
ET.register_namespace('', "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1")
r = ET.ElementTree(e)
```

You'll get the following resulting `XML` having the properties you stated you are looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"></assemblyIdentity>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0"></bindingRedirect>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="foo" value="default"></add>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I know I came late to the party.. Anyway hoping this will help you and many other having the same issue, here it is a good solution. Happy coding!