# How to add a subelement in xml

Tags: python, json, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

```
<data>
    <items>
        <item name="item1">....text here</item>
        <item name="item2">....another text here</item>
    </items>
</data>
```

I'm in stuck. 
I have this scheme of xml. I need to add an additional   block with (key,value) like this (name="something") and the text value. 
So, I need to make something like this

```
 <item name="item3">text here</item>
```

I know, that I can do something like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data = ET.Element('data')
items = ET.SubElement(data, 'items')
item1 = ET.SubElement(items, 'item')
item2 = ET.SubElement(items, 'item')
item1.set('name','item1')
item2.set('name','item2')
item1.text = 'another text here...'
item2.text = '...text here'
myExample = ET.SubElement(items, 'item')
myExample.set('name', 'For example')
myExample.text = 'for instance, its a string'


mydata = ET.tostring(data)
myfile = open("items2.xml", "wb")
myfile.write(mydata)
```

But I need to find another approach in order to do this.
And what is more, I want to figure it out how to add it to my xml file. Am I need to rewrite file or?...

```
myfile = open("items2.xml", "a+b")
myfile.write(mydata)
```

adds result into another string.. And it's causes error in xml.

---

I came up with a way that a bit solves my problem.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data = ET.Element('data')
items = ET.SubElement(data, 'items')

result = iter(['Price: 2250','Price: 1','Price: 2','Price: 3'])
l = [exec("f = ET.SubElement(items, 'item')\nf.set('name', 'order')\nf.text='%s'%next(result)") for _ in range(4)]

mydata = ET.tostring(data)
myfile = open("items2.xml", "wb")
myfile.write(mydata)
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake. Fixed it.
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have an existing XML document to which you want to add a new element? Because that is not what "a bit solves my problem" does. And why is the question tagged with "json"?

Comment: yes, y'r right. I need to add an additional subelement into existing file with the complete structure. i.e this file has a root (data), main subelement (items) and subelements inside items (i.e item). 
When special data arises in my program it should record this data into the item.text subelement of the xml file (like the example above).

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen the a+b mode. You want to create a new file with the changes added, which means w or wb in your case. You don't want to append since that just adds new data to the end of your previous file.

Also, why do you need to find another approach?

Comment: sry, I meant 'ab'
2 questions in my post :) 
1) I just need to add <item name="item 1">....text here</item> every time when new data comes (data = 'text' in my case)
I need to find an approach to do this. 
2) Am I need to use 'wb' mode to create a new file (or just change the content of the file) instead of adding some information through the 'ab' mode?  
If it's not possible, I'll close the issue

Comment: This question seems similar enough to yours. It hasn't been answered yet, but I would track it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438921/how-do-i-parse-and-write-xml-using-pythons-elementtree-without-moving-namespace